# Обособление вводного словца

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

`Я люблю одно имя, по-моему(,) красивое, – Бэла.`

А здесь запятые нужны?

`Я люблю одно имя(,) красивое(,) по-моему, – Бэла.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ах, **сложный вопрос!**

1. Ведь можно просто использовать всем известное **[правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)** (пункт 4) о том, что вводное слово не отделяется от обособленного оборота, и тогда запятая не нужна в обоих случаях. (Вероятно, именно такое решение **будет одобрено.)**
2. Но насколько **корректно** это правило в приведенных примерах? Другими словами, вводное слово мы по-прежнему считаем вводным, **но запятых нет?!** Но разве так бывает? Вводное слово обособляется, потому что по определению оно **не входит** в состав предложения.
3. Поэтому мне не нравится "клеить" **любое** вводное слово к **любому** обороту, вот что... Тогда надо считать, что это **другая часть речи** (наречие или присоединительный союз). Но эти варианты сюда не подойдут.

Кстати, это вводное слово может иметь **парное наречие**, но оно относится к предикативу: [Справочник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_417).

4. Поэтому предлагается такое решение:

(1) *Я люблю одно имя, **по-моему, красИвое**, – Бэла.*

(2) *Я люблю одно имя, **красИвое, по-моему**, – Бэла.*

**Перестановка** не вносит изменений в грамматику: пауза во втором примере более короткая, но это неважно. вводное слово остается **вводным словом**.

Comment: Так в справочнике "по моему мнению" = "по-моему". И тоже вводное. А наречие "по-моему" нельзя заменить на "по моему мнению".

Comment: Вы считаете, что нет наречия "по-моему"?  Например: Оно красивое по моему, а по-вашему не красивое, да?  Явно наречное выражение, это очевидно, можно и не заменять.  Семантика понятная.

Comment: Комментарий дополнил. В тех примерах наречие нельзя заменить.

Comment: Не понимаю ваше "Оно красивое по-моему". По моему желанию? **ПО-МОЕМУ. I. *нареч.* 1.** Так, как я, таким образом, как я. *Делай по-моему*. **2.** Так, как я хочу, по моему желанию. *Вышло по-моему*.

Comment: Можно посмотреть на тему обобщенно.  Во многих случаях существуют пары «наречие – вводное слово», и часто бывает так, что по семантике их трудно различить. Тогда надо учитывать грамматику и интонацию. Наречие может относиться как к прилагательному, так и к глаголу/сказуемому, но в обоих случаях оно находится в постпозиции, что определяется по ударению. Вот и надо поместить его в такую позицию, что мы и видим в данном случае.

Comment: А объяснять надо по правилам.  Ведь найти нужное правило для уже известного решения – тоже своего рода искусство,  как и задать вопрос с неочевидным правилом. Впрочем, можно дать ссылку на это правило и поставить все запятые…

Comment: Извините, моя невнимательность...

Comment: А правда, что можно ещё вот так написать, если я слово *красивое* не ставлю в качестве главного, а в качестве допслова? То есть: *Я люблю одно имя, красивое, – Бэла.*

Answer (score 0):

*Я люблю одно красивое имя – Бэла.*

Нет смысла выделять слово "красивое", от этого оно красивее не становится и речь не становится более аргументированной и связанной. При перестановке слов выглядит, что это проблемы с речью, как будто забываешь вовремя вставить слова, которые хотел сказать.

Добавления *по-моему* - это слово паразит, можно таких вводных слов навставлять, но речь от этого лучше не становится. Если ты пишешь без кавычек, то очевидно, что это по-твоему, а не по-моему. Или то, что ты говорил до этого было не по-твоему, а по-моему?

Я люблю, по-моему, не помню что.