# Запятая и вводное слово

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Есть же правило о неотделении вводных слов, стоящих в начале или в конце обособленного оборота!

`Этот котёнок, наверное(,) хороший, не будет нас обижать.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны варианты:

(1) *Этот котЁнок, **наверное хорОший**, не будет нас обижАть.*

Вводное слово относится **к обороту**.

(2) *Этот котёнок, **наверное**, хорОший, // не будет нас обижАть.*

Вводное слово входит **в состав предложения** с однородными сказуемыми.

Интонация различная.

Comment: Я бы во втором случае тире поставил, так как то, что он хороший, – причина, из-за которой он не будет обижать.

Comment: Это противоречит вашему этому ответу, т. к. там вводное тоже либо в начале, либо в конце: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475339/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%86%d0%b0.

Comment: Я полагаю, что запятой (в разговорном стиле и именно в этом предложении) достаточно.  Второе сообщение распространяет первое без конкретики отношений. Но тире можно поставить, если есть желание увеличить паузу.  //  В том ответе я говорила, что не каждое вводное слово можно присоединить к обороту. В данном случае это возможно ("наверное" может быть наречием).